# Multiplicative constant in integration of first order differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In the context of a physics calculation, I have the following differential equation:

$$\dfrac{\dot{a}}{a}=k a^{-3/2}$$

where $a=a(t)$, $\dot{a}=da/dt$ and $k$ is a fixed numerical constant related to cosmological parameters. I am trying to reproduce the result given in the book as the solution to this equation, which is the following:

$$a(t)\propto t^{2/3}$$

Since in this context we assume the condition $a(t_0)=1$, the book mentions later on that, in fact:

$$a(t)=\bigg(\dfrac{t}{t_0}\bigg)^{2/3}$$

My calculations are the following:

$$\dfrac{\dot{a}}{a}=k a^{-3/2}\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \dot{a}a^{1/2}=k\ \ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \dfrac{da}{dt}a^{1/2}=k\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \int a^{1/2}da=\int kdt\ \ \ $$

$$\Rightarrow\ \ \  \dfrac{a^{3/2}}{3/2}=kt+C\ \ \ \Rightarrow a(t)=\bigg(\dfrac{3}{2}kt+\dfrac{3}{2}C\bigg)^{2/3}=\bigg(\dfrac{3}{2}kt+C_0\bigg)^{2/3}$$

If I impose the condition $a(t_0)=1$, what I obtain is:

$$a(t_0)=1\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ 1=\bigg(\dfrac{3}{2}kt_0+C_0\bigg)^{2/3}\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \dfrac{3}{2}kt_0+C_0=1\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ C_0=1-\dfrac{3}{2}kt_0$$

Therefore, the final result would be:

$$a(t)=\bigg(\dfrac{3}{2}kt-\dfrac{3}{2}kt_0+1\bigg)^{2/3}$$

But this is not what the book proposes, and honestly, it looks ugly. Is it correct? Is there any way to obtain what the book states, or maybe the formulas in the book are just approximations used in physics? They seem to be neglecting the additive constant, and I am puzzled as to how I can get a multiplicative integration constant instead of an additive one, so that I have something of the form $a(t)=(Ct)^{2/3}$ to later get $C=1/t_0$ by imposing the condition $a(t_0)=1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to solve this mystery!

Comment: Your solution is fine. What does your book "propose"?

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you! It gives no explanation, only states that the solution is $a(t)=(t/t_0)^{2/3}$. It puzzles me. That solution is called the Einstein-de Sitter universe in cosmology, so I suppose the book has to be right and it is some kind of approximation...?

Comment: No, it makes sense only if $3kt_0=2.$ Oh but wait, this is the case in your "Einstein-de Sitter universe"!

Comment: More precisely, the original task should be/could have been a boundary value problem with $a(0)=0$ and $a(t_0)=1$ where $k$ is a free parameter (or an additional component of the solution with $\dot k=0$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Why do you say that $3kt_0=2$ is the case in the Einstein-de Sitter universe?

Comment: @AnneBauval After stating that $a(t)=(t/t_0)^{2/3}$, the book says that this means $k=(2/3)\cdot(1/t_0)$, but that already assumes that the solution is as it says, not the other way around.

Comment: I say that $3kt_0=2$  after glancing at [this](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_d%27Einstein-de_Sitter#Caract%C3%A9ristiques_principales). And it has to be that way (i.e. solving the ODE for that value of $k$ given $t_0$), otherwise $k$ has to appear  in the general solution, which is yours.